# Transform values when umarshaling

Tags: go, unmarshalling

Given the code below, is it possible to transform first name while it's being unmarshaled? Say I want to always have it be lowercase whether it is in the actual json or not.

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
}

func main() {
    jsonText := GetJsonFromSomewhere()
    var v Person
    json.Unmarshal(jsonText, &v)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a custom type that implements the `Unmarshaler` interface from the `encoding/json` package. [Here's a link to this interface](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler). Any type which implements `Unmarshaler` can be used as the type of a struct field when doing JSON unmarshalling. When doing the unmarshalling, `encoding/json` will use your implementation of the interface's `UnmarshalJSON` function to convert the JSON bytes to the field type.

So you could write an `UnmarshalJSON` function which includes changing the string values to lowercase.

Here's an example of what that could look like:

```
type LowerCaseString string

func (l *LowerCaseString) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    lowerCasedString := strings.ToLower(string(bytes))

    *l = LowerCaseString(lowerCasedString)

    return nil
}
```

Then, in your struct for JSON mapping, you can use your custom type instead of `string`:

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName LowerCaseString `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  LowerCaseString `json:"last_name"`
}
```

If you unmarshal into this struct, the values of FirstName and LastName will be lowercased (also note that you'll need to type convert them back to `string` to use them as `string`s).

```
testJSON := `{"first_name" : "TestFirstNAME", "last_name": "TestLastNAME"}`
var result Person

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(testJSON), &result)
if err != nil { /*handle the error*/ }

fmt.Println(result.FirstName) // prints "testfirstname"

var stringLastName string
stringLastName = string(result.LastName) // need to type convert from LowerCaseString to string

fmt.Println(stringLastName) // prints "testlastname"
```

[Here is the above code running in Go Playground.](https://go.dev/play/p/CELfstvrcqw)